# I have error in asp.net site

Tags: asp.net

```
 **I have error in local host**
```

[image]

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <configuration>
          <connectionStrings>
            <add name="conversationDB" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=Mojtaba;Initial Catalog=conversation;Integrated Security=True"/>
          </connectionStrings>
            <system.web>
please resolve this error for me thank you 
              <roleManager>
                <providers>
                  <add connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/"
                    name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
                </providers>
              </roleManager>
              <membership defaultProvider="Mymembershipprovider">
                <providers>
                  <add name="Mymembershipprovider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.MyRoleProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"/>
                </providers>
              </membership>
              <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MyRoleProvider">
                <providers>
                  <clear/>
                  <add name="MyRoleProvider" type="SecurityInASPNET.MyRoleProvider"/>
                </providers>
              </roleManager>
              <authentication mode="Forms">
                <forms name=".RememberMe" loginUrl="~/result.aspx" timeout="130000" slidingExpiration="true" defaultUrl="~/score/Mojtaba.aspx">
                </forms>
              </authentication>
              <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
              <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
            </system.web>
          <!--WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationModeخطای صفحه‌ی لاگین-->
          <appSettings>
            <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None"/>
          </appSettings>
          <!--WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationModeخطای صفحه‌ی لاگین-->
          <location path="score_Mojtaba.aspx">
            <system.web>
              <authorization>
                <deny users="?"/>
              </authorization>
            </system.web>
          </location>
        </configuration>
```

Comment: describe fully your question?

Comment: It tells there are two `roleManager` sections in your web.config. unite them into one section

Comment: what to do for solve it

Comment: I try to create login page in my website

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to have two roleManager section, remove the useless one.

Comment: As i said ,remove the useless roleManager section and keep only one

Comment: Edit your post with your new error  ( and the code that fire the error ), and i will see if i can help